# how to retrieve the name of checkbox if using dynamic name like this<input type="checkbox" name="<%=i%>" /> in servlet?

Tags: java

if provide the dynamic name to the check box and i want to retrieve name of it in servlet for using its value..

Comment: You have to provide a different name if that checkbox is somewhat different, if not it will be equal to the other checkboxes, from the name point of view.

Answer (score 1):

In the JSP, use it like the following in a loop

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<%="checkbox"+(i++)%>" />
```

Pass another additional varable, which contains the total number of dynamically generated checkboxes.

```
<input type="hidden" name="num_chk_boxes" value="<%=i%>" />
```

In the servlet firstly read the total number of checkboxes, from the request, and then do a request.getParameter("checkbox"+i) in a loop with the number as the counter.

Hope that solves your problem